# Virtual Box windows 8 on mac and the screen resolution is 1024x768 not 1366x768

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I am running windows 8 on a Virtual Box on a mac and the setting on the windows only allows 1024 x 768. I want 1366 x 768 so can somebody help?

Comment: did you install guest additions?

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments you need to install the "Guest Additions" (call it drivers) to be able to change screen resolution. To install the "Guest Additions" click "Devices" > "Insert Guest Additions CD image...". This will insert the CD-image to your guest OS.
[image: Insert Guest Additions CD image...]

The autorun will help you initiate the installation.
[image: Autorun]

After finishing the installation you should be able to change the resolution.
[image: Change resolution]